# I am getting coverity issuse as "Wrapper object use after free (WRAPPER_ESCAPE)"

Tags: c++, string, coverity

Hi  i am getting Coverity issue as **"Wrapper object use after free (WRAPPER_ESCAPE)1. escape: The internal representation of local hello escapes, but is destroyed when it exits scope"**  please help me to fix it

```
extern  const char * Helloworld()
{
  std::string hello = obj->myfunction();

  return hello.c_str();   // this is return to a c function
}
```

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory message, I should have thought. What specifically are you having trouble with about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string hello = obj->myfunction();
```

Is going to create a string with automatic storage.  Then you return a pointer to the underling `char*` with `return hello.c_str();`.  The problem with this is that at the end of the function (`}`) all automatic objects are destroyed.  This deletes the contents of the string that you just passed a pointer to.  Using the pointer in another function is undefined behavior as memory has been deallocated.

If you want to return a `char*` that is persistent then you need to allocate memory for the `char*` and copy the string into it.  You can do that
with:

```
extern  char * Helloworld()
{
    std::string hello = obj->myfunction();
    char * returner = new char[hello.size() + 1];
    strcpy(returner, hello.c_str());
    return returner;
}
```

With this the caller will have to delete the pointer when it is done with it otherwise there will be a memory leak.

Comment: Any good way to fix it  without effecting the code functionality?

Comment: @pravupp can't you just return the `std::string`?

Comment: my calling function is oriented in c style so i cannot use std::string as return type

Comment: @pravupp added to my answer.  let me know if that answers it for you.

Comment: thanks your ans is good one but one small doubt can i  take std::string hello as global in .h file ?

Comment: @pravupp you can but it is not considered good practice to have global variables.

Comment: I am facing same issue, but if i uses `new` and `strcpy`, I will get Autosar issues in coverity. Fixing static will result in autosar. Any other option available to fix static issues ?

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a dangling pointer here, which is never a good thing, and that's why coverity is complaining.

When you take `c_str()` from a `std::string`, that is a *non-owning* pointer of the underlying memory of the string. The memory will be freed when the `std::string` is destroyed, and the `const char *` will be left dangling.

In your case, when the function exits, the local variable `hello` is destroyed and the pointer that is returned is useless.

In general you should not take `c_str()` except in the immediate context of passing something to a C library function, or at least, that is the most straight-forward way to avoid these problems.